# Error while starting Spring Boot Eureka Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am getting the following error while trying to deploy a spring boot microservice project having service discovery module

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:
run (default-cli) on project serviceDiscovery: An exception occurred while running. null: 
InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded container; 
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: 
Unable to start embedded Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: 
Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: 
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: 
A child container failed during start ->
```

I have posted the pom.xml which I am using
    
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>in.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>serviceDiscovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>serviceDiscovery</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

The problem started with with spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.3.2.RELEASE. It started giving the following error

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find 
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-dependencies:pom:1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT 
in https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-snapshots 
has elapsed or updates are forced 
@ org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, 
/home/soumya/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies
/Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-dependencies-Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

I thought of increasing the spring-boot-parent version to 1.3.5 but it gave me another set of problems as provided at the beginning

Answer (score 3):

Okk, here is the solution. 
Keep the parent as

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Now add / modify the following dependency management

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Both versions of spring-boot-starter-parent (1.3.5 and 1.3.2) are working.
Actually I was using **Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT** in my dependency-management which has now been changed to **Brixton.RELEASE**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use spring-cloud-starter-parent instead of spring-boot-starter-parent.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find 
 org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:Brixton.RELEASE 
 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
 resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed 
 or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Comment: Its spring-cloud-starter-parent, not spring-boot-starter-parent. You should replace in groupId and artifactId.

Comment: I have posted the answer. Thanks @techtabu, u tipped me off. The Brixton.RELEASE should not go in the <parent> but in the <dependencyManagement>. It worked like charm

Comment: Cool. I am glad it worked. However, both solution should work. Also, you can add spring-boot-parent as well in dependency management (in spring-boot projects) if you want to maintain your organization's hierarchical structure (like you want to have some common parent pom or so).

Comment: We recommend NOT using `spring-cloud-starter-parent` as a parent.

Comment: We don't use it either. We have requirement to use Corporate parent pom. However, can you please let me know the reason. For my curiosity.