# Spring cloud netflix eureka server - tomcat error on startup

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

this is my first question at stackoverflow, so I try my best to describe everything in detail.
I have a simple spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server gradle based project which should only start the eureka server inside a docker container.
I am really new to spring. I tried some older versions of spring cloud starter but nothing worked.
I am building the jar on ubuntu 18.04 with openjdk 10.

It would be really nice if someone could help me!
Thanks a lot!

My SpringBootApplication class looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer; 

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServiceRegistryApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.3.RELEASE'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

And my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ADD ./build/libs/eureka-service-registry-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/eureka-service-registry-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

EXPOSE 8761
```

When I run my docker container (and also when I start the application from within IntelliJ) I get the following:

```
2018-07-02 19:31:51.732  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3aa9e816: startup date [Mon Jul 02 19:31:51 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-02 19:31:51.987  INFO 1 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-07-02 19:31:52.025  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a4e4f18] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-02 19:31:52.381  INFO 1 --- [           main] r.a.m.e.EurekaServiceRegistryApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-02 19:31:52.404  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@72d818d1: startup date [Mon Jul 02 19:31:52 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3aa9e816
2018-07-02 19:31:53.495  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0823e893-dcb5-3d08-bbb3-dc67f56037ba
2018-07-02 19:31:53.524  INFO 1 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-07-02 19:31:53.657  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a4e4f18] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-02 19:31:54.053  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2018-07-02 19:31:54.082  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-02 19:31:54.083  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-02 19:31:54.097  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-07-02 19:31:54.169 ERROR 1 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1186) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-07-02 19:31:54.170 ERROR 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at de.tudresden.inf.rn.amcs.microservices.eurekaserviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistryApplication.main(EurekaServiceRegistryApplication.java:11) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [eureka-service-registry-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [eureka-service-registry-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [eureka-service-registry-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [eureka-service-registry-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-07-02 19:31:54.171  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-02 19:31:54.172  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

Comment: add spring-boot-starter-web? It seems like there is the wrong version of the servlet spec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while starting Spring Boot Eureka Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777362/error-while-starting-spring-boot-eureka-server)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem.that spring-boot version must one-to-one match eureka version.you can reference to http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/

example:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
<parent>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select proper spring boot  and spring cloud version. Also, i was getting error for jettison hence added dependency for jettison to resolve this.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>eureka-server</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your comments! I first added the spring-boot-starter-web, then the error changed to something with gson.
The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031381/why-do-i-get-gson-builder-error-when-starting-a-spring-boot-application) solved my problem at the end.